# How to create a TButton or other controls inside a THintWindow?

Tags: delphi, hint

I am trying to create a THintWindow and place a TButton or a TFrame on it. here is my code:

```
TForm1 = class(TForm)
  Button1: TButton;
  Button2: TButton;
  procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
private
  HintWindow: THintWindow;
public
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  HintWindow := THintWindow.Create(Self);
  HintWindow.Color := clInfoBk;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  P: TPoint;
  R: TRect;
  Control: TControl;
begin
  Control := Button1;
  P := Control.ClientToScreen(Point(0, Control.Height));
  R := Rect(P.X, P.Y, P.x + 100, P.Y + 100);
  with TButton.Create(HintWindow) do
  begin
    Parent := HintWindow;
    Caption := 'My Button';
  end;
  HintWindow.ActivateHint(R, 'My Hint');
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  HintWindow.ReleaseHandle;
end;
```

The Hint window is shown but I don't see the TButton. it seems that there are no child windows inside the Hint window (I tested with Spy++ for "first child").
I also tried to subclass THintWindow with new CreateParams ie:

```
procedure TMyHintWindow.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  Params.Style := Params.Style or WS_CLIPCHILDREN;
  Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT;
end;
```

When I create a TFrame as child on the Hint window, Spy++ shows that there is a child on the hint window but I cant see it (even after I force it to be visible).

Any feed-backs on this?

Comment: That code works perfectly for me, no need for subclassing. What version of Delphi do you have?

Comment: @David Heffernan: Can you see that Button? I use D5.

Comment: D5. Urgh! Yes, I'm on XE2 and I can see the button perfectly well.

Comment: David, will it be too much to ask the source code of "THintWindow.Create" and "THintWindow.CreateParams" in your controls unit?

Comment: I've got D6. I'll have a dig there and see if I can see the behaviour you report. If so then it should be easy for me to work out what the diff is.

Comment: I can repro your behaviour in D6 and using the XE2 code in D6 makes the button appear. I'll continue searching.

Comment: @David, I have added:

    if Assigned(Screen.Activeform) then
    HintWindow.ParentWindow := Screen.ActiveForm.Handle
  else
    HintWindow.ParentWindow := Application.Handle;

before "ActivateHint" and it seems to work for me now. Maybe that is what's missing in the controls unit on the ActivateHint?

Comment: It seems that you and I came up with the same answer at the same time! I studied XE2 source code and the most obvious difference that jumped out was the setting of ParentWindow which there happens in `ActivateHint`. The XE2 code always sets it to Application.Handle so I think that's just the simplest approach. No need to try to set it to `ActiveForm.Handle`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't ask me why, but you can make this work in old versions of Delphi by setting the `ParentWindow` to `Application.Handle` immediately after you create the `THintWindow` instance:

```
HintWindow := THintWindow.Create(Self);
HintWindow.ParentWindow := Application.Handle;
```

This answer was inspired by the modern versions of the Delphi VCL source.